# Threads and garbage collection

Tags: c#, multithreading, garbage-collection, weak-references

I have a windows service which runs continuously and creates some threads to do some work. I want to make sure that these threads are properly disposed of (garbage collected after they are finished.

However, I also want to be able to check to see if they are alive periodically and terminate them if they are. I know I can't keep any references to them, though, because then they wouldn't be garbage collected.

Is there an alternative way to check for the existence/state of user-defined threads? I was thinking maybe something like the following using `WeakReference`: (I can't fully test right now or I'd just test it myself)

```
List<WeakReference> weakReferences;
Thread myThread = new Thread(() => Foo());
WeakReference wr = new WeakReference(myThread);
weakReferences.Add(wr);  //adds a reference to the thread but still allows it to be garbage collected
myThread.Start();
myThread = null;  //get rid of reference so thread can be garbage collected
```

and then at the beginning of my onTimeElapsed event (run every 5 minutes):

```
foreach(WeakReference wr in weakReferences)
{
    Thread target = wr.Target as Thread;  //not sure if this cast is really possible
    if(target.IsAlive && otherLogic)
    {
         target.Abort();
    {
}
```

But I'm not sure exactly how WeakReference works. Any ideas on how to properly do this?

Comment: The easiest way to ensure that your threads are cleaned up is simply to ensure that their work eventually terminates (successfully or otherwise).  I'm curious about the circumstances in which a thread could be spawned and you'd want to clean it up before it's work is complete.

Comment: Aborting a Thread is a very bad idea anyway. This will usually work but you have built in a time-bomb here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is `myThread` a method variable? or...?

In most scenarios, the thread *will* simply be garbage collected when possible. There is no need to set `myThread` to `null` if `myThread` is a method variable, because that *won't exist* at the time.

I would, however, note that threads are actually pretty expensive objects (the stack alone is a pain to allocate). If possible, I would suggest either using the `ThreadPool` (if each item is short-lived), or a bespoke work queue (if longer), potentially with multiple workers servicing a single queue.

As for terminating/aborting a thread... that is **never** a good idea; you have *no idea* what the thread is doing at that point. After that, it is *possible* that your entire process is doomed. If *at all* possible, consider having the worker check an "abort" flag occasionally. If not possible, consider doing the work in a separate *process*. A process is even more expensive than a thread, but it has the advantage that it is isolated; you can kill it without impacting yourself. Of course, you could still corrupt any files it was working on, etc...

Frankly, the main time I would ever consider aborting a thread is if my process is already dying, and I'm trying to put it out of misery ASAP.

Comment: To add a bit more to Marc's answer, you can see the [`Task<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class. It supports cancelation (if I am correct from .NET 3.5) and progress report (if I am correct from .NET 4.5).

Comment: @oleksii indeed, but cancellation is *not* the same as an arbitrary abort; for cancellation to work properly, the code itself needs to be cancellable

Answer (score 2):

Use thread pool. Don't spawn threads by yourself and don't invent the wheel.

Comment: But I like my wheels to have four sides!